# Change Carrier Density Of Semiconductor

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Do you know how you can actively modulate the carrier density in a semiconductor ?

Comment: It happens all the time in a transistor. Making non-equilibrium carrier concentrations is the heart of semiconductor devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, this is the bedrock of transistor operation. You can modulate the carrier density of a semiconductor through capacitive coupling.

Make the semiconductor one plate of a capacitor and apply a voltage across it. Charge gets drawn into the semiconductor through the contacts, and the carrier density changes.  This is the principle of a metal-oxide-semiconductor (MOS) capacitor, which is the primary component in a MOS field-effect transistor (MOSFET).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! :))
Maybe you also know the answer to my other question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409483/change-of-refractive-index-using-semiconductor?noredirect=1#comment917200_409483